# Email body with dynamic content in Java

Tags: java, email

I need to find a way how to send e-mails with dynamic content from my application in Java. In example:

Dear < Name > < Last name >,
this is your new password < password >.

So when i send the mail the tags will change their values: < Name >= user's name, < Last name >=user's last name, < password >= user's password

So can somebody give me an advice or send me a link of some tutorial?

Comment: Since your concern seems more to be the templating, not the sending of emails, you may consider to rephrase your title, question and tags to get rid of the email part since that's not your concern. It's just *another* step in your task.

Answer (score 2):

This involves the use of basic variables.  Have a look at [Sending Email using JavaMail API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) and use variables to set the users first and last name as well as their password as part of the body of the message.

Comment: Oren, the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

```
String template = "Dear {0} {1}, this is your new password {2}.";
String message = MessageFormat.format(template, "Jeff", "Atwood", "killskeet");
```

Alternatively, use [`String#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String template = "Dear %s %s, this is your new password %s.";
String message = String.format(template, "Jeff", "Atwood", "killskeet");
```

This only requires strict ordering of parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but i was looking for something like this: 
http://www.bredelet.com/Denis/FreeMarker%20first%20steps.html
or
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html

Comment: My answer is also something like that? Or do you want to use names in expressions and some more fanciness? Have a look at [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) then.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the message with a StringBuilder and insert the name, lastName, and password variables directly. Or you could write your message in a text file along with the variables (as you've written in your post) and parse the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache velocity to send emails with dynamic content. No strict ordering of parameters is required. you just need place holders and set them in velocity context. The template engine will replace the dynamic content.